# Annotate type of zipped tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, python-typing

I am experimenting with the type hints in Python 3.7.6

```
from typing import Tuple
v1: Tuple[int, int] = (3,4)
v2: Tuple[int, int] = (2,3)
# build the sum of the two vectors
mysum: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(v1, v2)) 
print(mysum)
```

This code works nicely. But mypy is not happy:

```
typedzip.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I am new to mypy. What options do I have to go from here? I would like to get rid of the mypy error (I have my IDE set up to mark all files with mypy errors in red - something I like a lot). Preferably without telling mypy to ignore this file or these kind of errors. Can I give more type hints?

I am aware that, in this simple case, I can replace the comprehension with a simple construction of a new two-value-tuple. Zipping seems to lose the type's awareness of its cardinality. But I am wondering whether I can help the type inference system by maybe giving more hints or tell it the cardinality of the tuple.

Comment: It seems zip (for mypy) is overloaded for typing to return `Tuple[int, ...]` for an input of 2-tuples:  https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L1449 . You could try to worsen your code to `mysum: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(v1, v2))[:2]` and see if that gets rid of your problematic typehint error

Comment: @Patrick: I tried the idea with [:2] already before posting. It does not help. I guessed it is because [:2] is also valid for shorter lists/tuples.